# Firebase Firestore retrieving user data from database returning error

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to retrieve user information from Firestore and it keeps showing me this below error message.

> Error = Listen for query at user failed: Missing or insufficient permissions

Firestore security rules:

```
match/user/{userId} {
  allow read: if request.auth.uid == userId;
  allow write: if true;
  allow update: if request.auth.uid == userId;
  allow delete: if request.auth.uid == userId;
}
```

Code

```
func getUser() {
    if let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
        db.collection("user").getDocuments { snapshot, error in
            if error == nil {
                if let snapshot = snapshot {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.userInfo = snapshot.documents.map { d in
                            return User(userId: d.documentID,
                                        email: d["email"] as? String ?? "",
                                        tokens: d["tokens"] as? Int ?? 0)
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Text("error")
            }
        }
    } else {
        Text("error")
    }
}
```

Has anyone dealt with this kind of issue?

If change the security rule to allow read: if request.auth.uid != null  = it returns user data from all the users in the database which is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your rules only grant the user permission to read their own document, but your code tries to get all documents from the collection. Security [rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#rules_are_not_filters), but rather ensure that your code doesn't request more data than it has access to.

So you'll need to update your code to only request the document(s) it has access to. Something like this:

```
db.collection("user").document(uid).getDocument { document, error in
  ...
```

---

Not related to the error, but note that your `update` and `delete` rules are not doing anything here - since you're already granting the user all `write` permissions on the same collection and that covers `create`, `update`, and `delete`. Since the `write` rule is more permissive, the others won't do anyting.

For more on this, check the Firestore documentation on [granular permissions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#granular_operations).